# ETS Operations Runtime

Tags: performance, hashmap, erlang, ets

What is the runtime of `delete_object` for the ets bag? Given that there are `n` entries with the same key `k`, would the runtime of `delete_object` be `O(n)` or `O(1)`? If it is indeed `O(1)`, how does the `lookup` operation return all tuples sorted by insert time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This post on the erlang mailing list is from 2011, but I would assume that it probably still holds:

http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2011-October/061705.html

The answer given by Sverker Eriksson implies that the lookup time would be `O(n)` wrt the number of equal keys:

> On average constant time for insert/lookup/removal of scattered keys. A 
>       bag with lots of identical keys may give bad performance as that will
>       result in linear searches between objects with the same key (and others
>       that happen to hash to the same bucket).